# Searching spotify and user music library for particular artist or genre

Tags: spotify

I am developing third party app on spotify platform.
In that, user have to select either his own library or have to choose spotify library.
So, I am trying to search user library and spotify library for particular **artist** or **genre**
I am having following code snap,

var search = new models.Search("akon");

```
search.localResults = models.LOCALSEARCHRESULTS.APPEND;

search.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE, function() {

    search.artists.forEach(function(artist) {

        console.log(artist.name);

    });

});

search.appendNext();
```

But I am getting following errors,

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'APPEND' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'observe'**

Is there are functions to search both user library and spotify library for particular genre and artist 
or I have to use any third party library for this type of functionality.
If so, then Suggest me about any third party library that provide this type of functionality.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the latest preview build (available here: http://developer.spotify.com/en/spotify-apps-api/preview/) - that's why you're getting errors.

For using search, see the documentation here: http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/preview/reference/833e3a06d6.html

Finally, there's no way to "search" the user's library other than by looping through the items in the `library.albums`, `library.artists` and `library.tracks` methods. Again, see the docs.

Comment: Please can you tell me what if I want to search only spotify library for particular artist or genre and why I am getting error in above code snipet. I have taken same from the spotify latest api. thank you.

Comment: After getting latest preview build search function is working. thanks iKenndac.

Comment: don't repeat written things. text stays there, it is not like "saying something"!

Comment: Are you taking offence to the fact I pointed out that two separate things are documented? By that logic my entire answer should've been "Read the documentation."